# Redirecionamento de páginas 404 para pesquisa

Tags: php, magento

Olá, tenho um site em magento e algumas páginas de produtos não existem mais, porem existem outros produtos com nomes similares. O que acontece?
Muitos desses links estão sendo acessados ainda, o que gostaria de fazer é quando um erro 404 seja encontrado no site e STRING URI seja redirecionada para a pesquisa

```
EX:
http://www.loja.com.br/index.php/iphone6-16gb-preto.html
Irá redirecionar para:
http://www.loja.com.br/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=iphone6+16gb+preto
```

Assim terei o usuário na página ainda e vai mostrar outros produtos que encontrar na pesquisa.

Vlw pessoal.

Comment: Tem certeza que quer prosseguir com isso? É péssimo para SEO. Se vc confirmar que realmente quer fazer assim, eu te mostro como fazer.

Comment: Era justamente para SEO que foi feito. Erro 404 não é uma boa.

Comment: Comigo funcionou... Editei apenas 1 produto e ele identificou os demais... Coloquei aquele produto como URL TEMPORARIA.

Answer (score 1):

O jeito mais fácil de fazer é utilizar o módulo de rewrite de URL do próprio magento.

Vá no admin backend -> Catalog -> Url Rewrite e adicione as rotas desejadas.

Comment: creio que está seria a opção para editar produto por produto, se ele ainda existisse teria ele listado no catalogo, porem os links que estao na web de produtos nao existem, mais por isso gera o ERRO 404. Quero uma solucao no magento para lidar com esse erro 404 e redirecionar para a pesquisa, pois existe produtos com nomes parecidos.

Comment: essa opção voce nao precisa mais ter o produto, somente a url dele entrada e destino simples assim

Comment: então muito ruim de fazer assim, tem muito produto, muda muita coisa a toda hora, tem que ser mais dinamico, dessa forma nao é a mais facil pra mim aqui fica muito trabalho, por isso to tentando redirecionar pelo erro 404, acho que ja vou conseguir e posto aqui.

Comment: @rafaelphp podem existir varias formas eu te passei uma delas, é interessante tambem você mostrar alguma tentativa, algum esforço da sua parte

Comment: esse não é o jeito mais fácil.. é na verdade o modo mais adequado/correto. Mas o AP parece querer ir para um caminho errado, que a princípio é mais fácil.